# Fantasy Novel where the main character could summon shadows

Tags: story-identification, books, novel, sword-and-sorcery

This was a book I read several years ago. It was in the Sword & Sorcery genre, and the main character can summon shadows. He had a connection to the world of shadows and was the child of a human and a 'shadow' princess.  He would summon the shadows to attack his foes by crawling into their armor and biting.

Comment: Summoning shadows is a relatively common theme in fantasy; https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/43542754-shadowmancer